# Threading.Tasks: Concept of WaitAll()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I'm experiencing a strange issue in a **console** application (unsure if this has something to do with it) and using Tasks.

Most examples show purposely invoking an Exception to test/explain the concept of WaitAll - but in my case, it *seems* I'm doing something fundamentally wrong (or don't fully understand).

```
Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(()=> foo(arg));
Task<int> task2 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(()=> bar(arg));

Task<int>[] tasks = {task1, task2};

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks); //hits this far

     if((int)task1.Result * (int)task2.Result == 99) //this seems to never get hit
     {
         System.Environment.Exit(0); //so this isn't called             
     }
     else
     {
         System.Environment.Exit(1); // neither is this called
     }
 }
 catch
 {
     .....
```

In the above it seems that the `if` block isn't hit so neither Exit Codes are returned - the console app therefore hangs.

No exception is thrown either - I can confirm this because **all** the tasks are in fact completed - I just didn't include the `catch` section above for brevity.

The tasks are completed quickly - they're not hanging so its not as if Task.WaitAll is still waiting - or perhaps it is, and that's something I'm missing (what is it waiting for)?

Any thoughts, advice or brutal corrections? Thanks!

Comment: We need to know more about the tasks. Your understanding of WaitAll is correct, it will either return when the tasks are completed, or will throw an exception if one was thrown in any task. (note that the exception(s) will only be thrown after all the tasks are completed)

Comment: The snippet really needs to demonstrate that either foo or bar is throwing an exception.  You should otherwise have no problem diagnosing this with the debugger, it will clearly show your catch block getting hit.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need the `(int)` casts, the type of `Result` is already `(int)` in your case.

Comment: Thanks all - I'll get back to you on this. I'm going by @caesay about a task hanging/not returning a value - **even if foo or bar actually does what they need to do**, no exceptions/verified - so I'll have to look into perhaps why either may not be returning value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the sake of argument I did a little test (shown below) - it demonstrates one of your tasks is hanging, and not returning a value.

```
        Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return 10;
        });
        Task<int> task2 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 15);
        Task<int>[] tasks = {task1, task2};
        try
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("tasks completed in {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

If you run that, it will print `tasks completed in 2000ms` (give or take a few milliseconds). All I did was copy/paste your code and add in my own tasks.

So where you say `"The tasks are [...] not hanging..."` that is false - they must be hanging.

Comment: Thanks I'll do more digging into one task that I maybe assuming is completed. It involves [SSH.Net](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) - it does what it needs to do (writes a file to SFTP location) but perhaps this task isn't properly returning an int value.

Comment: Thanks - this was in fact the issue. There seems to be some [intermittent issue with SSH.NET Disconnect()](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/workitem/792). While the issue is marked as closed, seems it shouldn't be. [Another issue](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/workitem/1140) points to Disconnect() that sounds related. In any case, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

As explained by caesay above, the tasks must be hanging. To check this I would suggest giving a default time out to your WaitAll call. You can do this by passing in an int which represents the number of milliseconds that the call must wait for the tasks to be over in. Try this

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks, 10000); //Set to wait for 10 seconds
```

Then see if there is an exception or whether your "if" statement is hit. If this works then experiment with larger time intervals to see what is going on with tasks.

Also I would recommend running the code that is within foo and bar without tasks (i.e. sequentially) as a test harness to understand if there is any particular problem with these two sample methods.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This *may* not work out since I'm waiting on return values - re: it will therefore always "fail" *even if they actually performed the task*. I know this sounds odd - but in my case the tasks do complete without exception. Either (or both) of them just isn't returning a value for some reason (I already have a suspect in a 3rd party open source lib).

Comment: So when you say that the "tasks do complete without exception", the if block must be hit as it is the next logical statement in the execution model. Are you implying that "if" statement never executes or it does execute but there is no return value from the tasks?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Issue identified and resolved. `if` wouldn't run intermittently (issue with lib - see above). Task was really **partially completed** (because it wouldn't return a value - I was only looking at 1 part of the task).